# Undo edits.? Not sure if that's what their called

Tags: gmail

Don't know what everything is called but I have an original of an email and it has been edited. Is there a way to take those edit out. Does that make sense..

Answer (score 1):

The Compose window in Gmail has a backwards curved arrow in the lower left corner which when clicked will undo edits. The Undo button will undo multiple edits if it is clicked multiple times. The forward curved arrow next to the Undo button ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> ) is the Redo button ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> ).

[image: Undo button in Gmail]

Gmail automatically saves drafts of email messages as you compose them. Another way of undoing an edit is to click the Drafts option at the left side of Gmail, select a saved draft, and edit it. When a saved draft is open for editing Gmail remembers its history and the Undo button works on saved drafts too. The Undo button worked when I tried it on a draft that was saved on the same day, but it didn't work on the same draft four days after the last day that it was saved.